# ¿Cómo mantener un Menú de Navegación Lateral Deslizante, de forma activo al recargar la página usando php, HTML y Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, menú

Lo que pasa es que tengo un menú lateral que se abre al abrir con un botón, sin embargo cuando recarga la página el menú vuelve a su forma de inicio y cierra el menú abierto.

Quiero que el menú se quede abierto y que solo se cierre cuando yo le de `click` al botón de cerrar. Que no se cierre el menú al recargar la página sólito. Ya lo intente con un código `javascript` y no me funciono, necesito ayuda, les anexo el código de mi menú.

Comment: Hola Gibran, no has añadido tu código, te recomiendo echar un vistazo al [tour] y [ask].

Comment: Por otra parte te daré una pista de como puedes hacerlo hasta que presentes un [mcve]. ¿Has probado a instanciar una variable de sesión en la que se guarde el esta del menú (abierto o cerrado)?

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos maneras, como comentaba otro compañero, crear una variable de sesión o una cookie donde guarde el estado del menú.

La otra manera es usar Ajax para hacer todas las consultas a PHP. De esta manera no hace falta recargar la pagina.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo usando esta página, anexare mi código cuando pueda para que tengan una idea,